# Does files that are created in an android application remain in the phone or do they get deleted when the application closes?

Tags: java, android, file

I have this code which creates a file in internal phone memory:

```
 File fileDir = getFilesDir();
    String filedir=fileDir.toString();
    String strNewFileName =  "information.csv";
    String strFileContents = (mes + "," + lat + "," + lng);

    File newFile = new File(fileDir, strNewFileName);
    try{


            boolean filestat = newFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo =
            new FileOutputStream(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
            fo.write(strFileContents.getBytes());
            fo.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    {Log.v("TEST","Exception on create ");}

   System.out.print(OpenFileDialog("information.csv"));


}
```

And i have this code to read and print the file:

```
public ArrayList<String> OpenFileDialog(String file){

    //Read file in Internal Storage
    FileInputStream fis;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
    fis = openFileInput(file);
     String line = "string";
     BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {

      list.add(line);
      System.out.println(list);
 }
         fis.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return list;

  }
```

However the code just returns me the one string that its added during this run of the application. I want to run the application multiple times and get all the lines of the file. Is my code wrong or does the file gets emptied after application is closed?

Comment: Open the file in append mode

Answer (score 0):

> Is my code wrong

You are creating a new file each time. Try [the version of `openFileOutput()` that takes the mode parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), using `MODE_APPEND`.

> does the file gets emptied after application is closed?

No, it does not.